# Html.Glass helper not found after installing Glass Mapper v4

Tags: glass-mapper

I've installed Glass.Mapper.Sc (v4.3.4.196) with out any problems but in a razor view i can't use helper `@Html.Glass()` because i have an error that says that HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for `Glass` and no extension method `Glass`... i'm missing something?

Comment: Do you have the Glass.Mapper references in your project? Before you install Glass.Mapper you need to reference the Sitecore.Kernel to make it work.

Comment: Yes, i have `Sitecore.Kernel`, `Glass.Mapper`,`Glass.Mapper.Sc` and `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc` references

Comment: Do you have the `@using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc` at the begining of your View?

Comment: Adding that, i have the error `The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'` (i have that reference)

Comment: Which MVC version you have installed? Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086850/the-type-expression-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced

Comment: I have v5.2.3, wich version needs Glass Mapper?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52932/discussion-between-tamas-tarnok-and-phoenix-uy).

Comment: @Phoenix_uy : What worked for me (VS2017 and .NET 4.6, MVC 5.2) was adding the reference to this assembly in web.config.
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        </assemblies>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was with MVC setup in the project not with Glass. This was the solution - http://samirvaidya.blogspot.hu/2015/10/the-type-expression-is-defined-in.html.

The error was exactly

> The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

And non of the HtmlExtensions was not working.
Solution is that you need the following references in your **web.config**.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 6):

I added

```
@using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc
```

on Top and it solved my problem